# How to search for what's between two words in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm doing a little script in bash.
I have a file with this string.

```
"https://example.example.com/abcde,"
```

The first part "https://example.example.com/" always stays the same, while the second part "abcde" always changes. (the "," at the end is always there).

Is there a command to find out what's in place of "abcde" and save it in a variable?

Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can the part after the _.com_ also contain slashes? Also, please post your own attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With `cut`:

```
$ var="$(echo "https://example.example.com/abcde,"  | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev)"
$ echo $var
abcde,
```

With `awk`:

```
$ var="$(echo "https://example.example.com/abcde,"  | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')"
$ echo $var
abcde,
```

Comment: Nice solution. Maybe print the second last column with delimiter '/' and ',' like `awk -F '[/,]' '{print $(NF-1) }'`

Answer (score 0):

So filter out the first part.

```
variable=$(sed 's~^https://example.example.com/~~' file.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this way it will save the whole string. Instead I want it to save only "abcde".

Comment: No, it will not. It will save only abcde, [repl link bash](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SpitefulAccomplishedSysadmin#main.sh)

Comment: If I had something before the string the command doesn't work (for example if I have "hello, https: //example.example.com/abcde,"). Would there be a way to make it work the same? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You have to grep first after the URL in the file and then pipe in this sed.

Comment: You could `'s~.*https://example.example.com/~~`. I recommend learning regex with crosswords online.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. What if I wanted to remove the "," at the end of the string in the variable?

Comment: then you should follow a good sed introduction and maybe do `'s~.*https://example.example.com/~~; s/,$//'` or `.*https://example.example.com/\(.*\),\?~\1~`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks a lot. What if I want to eliminate everything after "abcde"? (for example if I have "hello,https: //example.example.com/abcde,hello").

Comment: Then use `var=$(grep -oP 'https://example.example.com/\K.*(?=,)' file.txt)`

Comment: You could `s~.*https://example.example.com/\(.*\),.*~\1~`

Answer (score 0):

`variable=$(grep -oP "^"https:\/\/example.example.com\/(.*,")$" (name of file))`

Using regular expressions. You could use the alias to make this into a command, and then you only have to enter the alias name, to run the command.

Comment: Does not work for me, but looks interesting. Why do you think that only the last matching group would be printed with that command?

Comment: Forgot about just keeping the capture group in the output. I have edited this.

Comment: There are 2 parentheses open and 3 closing. How do you catch only the group that you want if it would running?

Comment: The information in the brackets are for the reader to know, I would enter the filepath and name of file, it is not for the command

Answer (score 0):

Only print the matching part of a `grep` with the `-o` option:

```
echo "https://example.example.com/abcde," | grep -o '[^/]*$'
```

You can delete the ',' with

```
echo "https://example.example.com/abcde," | grep -o '[^/]*$' | sed 's/,$//g'
```

and save it to a variable with

```
var=$(grep -o '[^/]*$' my_file.txt | sed 's/,$//g')
```

This only works fine if there is only one line with a slash in the whole file ;)